# Asking for new permissions once the app has been authorised using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have users who have authorised my app and are using it.  I now need to request further permissions on top of this and I remember reading that the Javascript SDK has some inbuilt methods which allow you to just request the permissions which have not already been handed over.  I've looked around a fair bit but I can't find any information on this anymore.

Can someone confirm that this exists, and if possible, how I can do this?  I actually switched from using the PHP SDK for the login just because I read about this feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this in the php-sdk as well. What you need to do is inspect the permissions connection and see if the user has granted the required permission to your app

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
```

If not you can either redirect them to the auth dialog, or prompt them with a button and explain why you want them to authenticate again.
You can view a sample response at

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions
```

Alternatively,using the Auth Dialog

```
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/
```

might also achieve what you are after, though this only works on referrals from Facebook I believe

Answer (score 0):

It's the same procedure as with users who have disconfirmed a permission. In that case the documentation for invalid access tokens applies: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/

So, you just need to reauthenticate the user including the additional permissions in the scope parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check for granted permissions, then if they are not the same as the ones you need then just redirect them to log in with he extended permissions you require and that's it.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/